# contextClick() is not working with IEWebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, internet-explorer-11, katalon-studio

In my test cases i'm using contextClick(). In Chrome and Firefox it is working well. But in Internet Explorer no action is performed. No error message is displayed in logs.

os = Windows 10 64bit

katalonVersion = 6.3.3.11

InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit) 3.150.0.0

ieVersion = 11.0.140

**Capabilities**

```
2019-09-10 12:07:29.425 INFO  c.k.k.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory    - Starting 'IE' driver
2019-09-10 12:07:29.432 INFO  c.k.k.c.w.util.WebDriverPropertyUtil     - User set preference: ['nativeEvents', 'false']
2019-09-10 12:07:29.433 INFO  c.k.k.c.w.util.WebDriverPropertyUtil     - User set preference: ['handlesAlerts', 'true']
2019-09-10 12:07:29.434 INFO  c.k.k.c.w.util.WebDriverPropertyUtil     - User set preference: ['enablePersistentHover', 'false']
2019-09-10 12:07:29.435 INFO  c.k.k.c.w.util.WebDriverPropertyUtil     - User set preference: ['requireWindowFocus', 'true']
2019-09-10 12:07:29.436 INFO  c.k.k.c.w.util.WebDriverPropertyUtil     - User set preference: ['javascriptEnabled', 'true']
2019-09-10 12:07:29.437 INFO  c.k.k.c.w.util.WebDriverPropertyUtil     - User set preference: ['cssSelectorsEnabled', 'true']
2019-09-10 12:07:29.438 INFO  c.k.k.c.w.util.WebDriverPropertyUtil     - User set preference: ['enable_element_cache_cleanup', 'true']
2019-09-10 12:07:29.439 INFO  c.k.k.c.w.util.WebDriverPropertyUtil     - User set preference: ['ie_ensure_clean_session', 'true']
2019-09-10 12:07:29.439 INFO  c.k.k.c.w.util.WebDriverPropertyUtil     - User set preference: ['window-size', '[1920, 1080]']
2019-09-10 12:07:29.439 INFO  c.k.k.c.w.util.WebDriverPropertyUtil     - User set preference: ['requireWindowFocus ', 'true']
```

**First Approach:**

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver)

WebElement testFolder = CustomKeywords.'com.cartago.katalon.keywords.ElementUtil.getElementByClassAndText'('x-tree3-el', GlobalVariable.SeleniumTestFolder)

action.click(testFolder).build().perform()         //OK

action.contextClick(testFolder).build().perform() //NOK
```

**Second Approach:**

```
TestObject to = CustomKeywords.'com.cartago.katalon.objects.TestObjects.fromElement'(testFolder)

WebUI.rightClick(to) //NOK
```

In both cases WebElement and TestObject is found by WebDriver.

**Log:**

```
2019-09-10 10:38:55.345 DEBUG testcase.ConvertWebElement               - 7: rootFolder = com.cartago.katalon.keywords.ElementUtil.getElementByClassAndText("x-tree3-node", "root")
2019-09-10 10:38:56.393 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - com.cartago.katalon.keywords.ElementUtil.getElementByClassAndText is PASSED
2019-09-10 10:38:56.394 DEBUG testcase.ConvertWebElement               - 8: to = com.cartago.katalon.objects.TestObjects.fromElement(rootFolder)
2019-09-10 10:38:56.538 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - com.cartago.katalon.objects.TestObjects.fromElement is PASSED
2019-09-10 10:38:56.539 DEBUG testcase.ConvertWebElement               - 9: doubleClick(to)
2019-09-10 10:38:58.010 DEBUG testcase.ConvertWebElement               - 10: delay(delayShort)
2019-09-10 10:38:59.021 DEBUG testcase.ConvertWebElement               - 11: testFolder = com.cartago.katalon.keywords.ElementUtil.getElementByClassAndText("x-tree3-el", SeleniumTestFolder)
2019-09-10 10:39:00.800 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - com.cartago.katalon.keywords.ElementUtil.getElementByClassAndText is PASSED
2019-09-10 10:39:00.801 DEBUG testcase.ConvertWebElement               - 12: to2 = com.cartago.katalon.objects.TestObjects.fromElement(testFolder)
2019-09-10 10:39:00.927 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - com.cartago.katalon.objects.TestObjects.fromElement is PASSED
2019-09-10 10:39:00.927 DEBUG testcase.ConvertWebElement               - 13: contextClick(testFolder).perform()
```

It would be great if anybody can give advice to resolve this problem.

Comment: The capabilities you use when creating your driver instance of IE are critical in determining how the driver behaves. The `requireWindowFocus` capability forces the driver to use a different mechanism to simulate user interaction. What happens when you try that?

Comment: I've added requiereWindowFocus with no effect. Pls see edited Questions with all my capabilities.

Comment: Did you try with chrome or Firefox?

Comment: As i mentioned in the question, Chrome and FF are working well.

Comment: My bad there, @JanZ, \IE and Edge browsers and not working well with Katalon for me also and it did below steps. ```Download this file: https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/4/2/342316D7-EBE0-4F10-ABA2-AE8E0CDF36DD/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe 262.
After download, copy/replace it into edge driver of Katalon Studio folder, e.g: C:\6.2\Katalon Studio Windows 64\configuration\resources\drivers\edgedriver```

Comment: So, i replaced IE WebDriver manually to version 3.2 and it worked for me. @lahimadhe pls formulate answer and i can accept it.

Comment: Sure, Thanks for that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below steps:

Step 1: Download this file:https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/4/2/342316D7-EBE0-4F10-ABA2-AE8E0CDF36DD/MicrosoftWebDriver

Step 2: After download, copy/replace it into edge driver of Katalon Studio folder, e.g: C:\6.2\Katalon Studio Windows 64\configuration\resources\drivers\edgedriver